# how to remove quote and slash from string in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

Hi friends... I am using regular expression so I get string but with double quote and slash but I dont want that. I want string value without slash and double quotes. I try this I'm but not getting proper answer.

I get error after running application `[/Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/RegexKitLiteDemo/Classes/RegexKitLiteDemoAppDelegate.m:108:0 /Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/RegexKitLiteDemo/Classes/RegexKitLiteDemoAppDelegate.m:108: error: incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void (^)(struct NSString *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)', expected 'void (^)(struct objc_object *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)`
I get this error line

Second one is this :        `[/Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/RegexKitLiteDemo/Classes/RegexKitLiteDemoAppDelegate.m:105:0 /Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/RegexKitLiteDemo/Classes/RegexKitLiteDemoAppDelegate.m:105: warning: 'NSString' may not respond to '+stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`

I get this error line `[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

```
    //NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus);  


    [connection release];
    //
    NSString *regexString = @"Stations\\[""(.*)""\\] = new Station\\((.*)new Array\\((.*)\\)\\);";  //@"Stations\\[""(.*)""\\] = new Station\\((.*)\\);"; //@"Stations\[""(.*)""\] = new Station\({[\,,2}(.*)new Array\((.*)\)\);";    //@"<a href=([^>]*)>([^>]*) - ";
    matchArray = [loginStatus arrayOfCaptureComponentsMatchedByRegex:regexString];
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[matchArray count]];
    //NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];
    [matchArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *aString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
    {
        NSString *newString = [NSString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];//#############
        [newArray insertObject:newString atIndex:idx];
        NSLog(@"matchArray: %@", matchArray);
    }];//******************


    //NSLog(@"matchArray: %@", matchArray);


    lstAirports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[matchArray count]];

    for (int i = 0; i < [matchArray count]; i++) {
        airport *air=[[airport alloc]init];

        //code
        air.Code = [[matchArray objectAtIndex: i] objectAtIndex: 1];
        NSLog(@"air.Code: %@\n",air.Code);
        //name
        NSString *temp=[[matchArray objectAtIndex: i] objectAtIndex: 2];
        NSArray *arrParts=[temp componentsSeparatedByString:@""","];
        //air.Name=arrParts[2];
        air.Name=[arrParts objectAtIndex:2];
        NSLog(@"air.Name: %@\n",air.Name);
        //destination airports
        temp=[[matchArray objectAtIndex: i] objectAtIndex: 3];
        arrParts=[temp componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        air.DestinationAirports =arrParts;
        NSLog(@"air.DestinationAirports: %@\n",air.DestinationAirports);
        [lstAirports addObject: air];
        NSLog(@"lstAirports: %@\n",lstAirports);
    }

    //[webData release]; 
}
```

please some help me fast it's vital for me

Answer (score 4):

You don't need RegExp to remove occurrences of string in NSString.

See the example below, i hop it will help you:

```
NSString *str = @"fdf\"fdsfdsf\"fsdfsf/fsdfsdfsf\\fsdfsdf\\fsdffsd//fsdfsf\"fsdf/\\\"";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: what is "fdf\"fdsfdsf\"fsdfsf/fsdfsdfsf\\fsdfsdf\\fsdffsd//fsdfsf\"fsdf/\ friend please explan me

Comment: It is just example string. Replace it with your one

Answer (score 0):

Check for the usage of

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString`:

in

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html.

You can replace them with "" characters.